# Json me trae parametro en comillas

Tags: javascript

Hola amigos tengo mi siguiente json que es respondido desde el backend:

```
{
    "reportUser": [
        {
            "idUser": 1,
            "firstname": "Andres",
            "AttemptDate​": "2022-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
            "idSession": 1,
            "timeSpent": 60,
            "idModule": 1,
            "name": "Sum",
            "score": "aprove"
        },
    ]
}
```

y en react cuando consumo el API me llega así.

```
{ 
  idUser: 1, 
  firstname: "Andres", 
  "AttemptDate​": "2022-06-01T00:00:00.000Z", 
  idSession: 1, 
  timeSpent: 60, 
  idModule: 1, 
  name: "Sum", 
  score: "aprove" 
}
```

Si se dan cuenta AttemptDate​ me llega asi "AttemptDate". Mi pregunta es por que pasa esto, y como hago para llamar desde llamada script un dato con "" comillas.​

Comment: extraño, como lo consumes, como llamas la información?

Comment: const getReportByUser = (idUser) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return Axios.get(`${REACT_APP_API_URL}/metrics/reportUser/${idUser}`)
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_REPORT_USER,
                    payload: response.data
                });
            })
    }
}

Comment: Te lo pone entre comillas porque el nombre de ese atributo posee un caracter especial no imprimible. Cuando copio y pego el objeto en un editor se muestra el caracter no imprimible. Si tienes acceso al backend, revisa cómo se está generando la respuesta. Saludos

Comment: Es exactamente lo que dice Mauricio Contreras, aún así hay una opción de acceder a una propiedad de un json aunque esta tenga comillas. Si el json se llamara `user` por ejemplo sería `user["AttemptDate"]`. Aunque en este caso no creo que te funcione por el caracter no imprimible que te aparece

Comment: Pues lo solucione como dijiste..

Answer (score 0):

es un carácter no convencional

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

recomiendo limpiar el string antes de utilizarlo

Comment: Como puedo limpiar el string?

Comment: filtrando con expresiones regulares, permitiendo solo numeros letras y uno que otro caracter que necesites, o buscar la posicion de ese caracter y eliminandolo